# I can't add the score with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to make a quiz app and I want to add the highest score but when I tap on the correct answer button, coinLabel has `Matcoin = 10` text. Then I tap on the correct answer button again it should have the text `Matcoin = 20` but it has `Matcoin = 10` instead. It's not adding a score.

here is my code:

```
var coin = 0
func addCoin() {

    if soruSayisi >= 1 && soruSayisi <= 12 {
        //if the number of questions is between 1 and 12
        coin = coin + 10

    else {
        print("error")
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(coin, forKey: "coin")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    coinLabel.text = NSString(format: "Matcoin =  %i", coin) as String

}
@IBAction func AbuttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    if "A" == cvpLbl {

        addCoin()
        //correct answer
    }


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let coinString = String(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "coin"))
    coinLabel.text = "Matcoin = \(coinString)"
}
```

Comment: Do you have this error when closing and reopening the app? If this is the case, it is because you are not taking the content of the UserDefaults and storing it in the coin variable at startup. In viewWillAppear you could write something like `coin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "coin")
coinLabel.text = "Matcoin = \(coin)"`. This way at startup the variable coin will always contain the value you stored in UserDefaults.

Comment: i don't have any error when i closing and reopening the app. and i wrote that code in viewWillappear you can see at below of codes.

Comment: look at the differences between my code and yours. I am storing the value taken from UserDefaults in the coin variable, you are not. I'm doing the same thing as @kd02 suggested. He is doing it every time you have to add coins, I'm doing it only when view will appear because it doesn't make sense to read it every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is cause when your calling addCoin() your not reading the coin value from userDefaults

```
func addCoin() {

    coin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "coin")

    if soruSayisi >= 1 && soruSayisi <= 12 {

        coin = coin + 10

    else {

        print("error")
        return
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(coin, forKey: "coin")

    coinLabel.text = String(coin)
}
```

Comment: The call to `synchronize` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `viewWillAppear` read the value from `UserDefaults`, assign it to `coin` and to the label. **Don't forget to call `super`**

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       coin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "coin")
       coinLabel.text = "Matcoin = \(coin)"
   }
   ```
2. In `addCoin()` first check if `soruSayisi` is in range `1..12`. If yes, increment coin by 10, write it to `UserDefaults` and update the label. The line to read from `UserDefaults` is redundant if `coin` is up-to-date. The code uses the pattern matching operator `~=` to check the range and the *addition assignment operator* `+=` to increment the value:

   ```
   func addCoin() {
       if  1...12 ~= soruSayisi {
           coin += 10
           UserDefaults.standard.set(coin, forKey: "coin")
           coinLabel.text = "Matcoin = \(coin)"
       } else { print("error") }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't make coin a computed property so when you use it, it automatically takes the newest value and updates the label?

```
var coin = 0 {
  didSet {
    coinLabel.text = "Matcoin =  \(coin)"
  }
}

func addCoin() {
    if soruSayisi >= 1 && soruSayisi <= 12 {
        //if the number of questions is between 1 and 12
        coin += 10
    }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(coin, forKey: "coin")
}

@IBAction func aButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if "A" == cvpLbl {

        addCoin()
        //correct answer
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    coin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "coin"))
}
```

Comment: The call to synchronize is unnecessary.

Comment: Your `did set` syntax it is wrong. Should be `didSet`. Btw Swift native string type is `String` and it has all the same initializers as `NSString` so using `NSString` initializer and casting to `String` is pointless

Comment: I refactored is code on a logic point of view...for the didSet it was an error in typing over the browser...

However I will refactor everything for correctness...

Edit: now it should be better...